# Express Validator to validate time

Tags: express, validation, express-validator

I want to validate Time like this 18:14 with [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/). When i used isTime as stated in [validator](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js) like this `body("StartTime").isTime().withMessage("Value must be time with HH:MM format")` throwing an error isTime is not a function.

Is there any other approach to achieve Time validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Regex?

```
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

body('StartTime')
  .custom((value) => {
    if (!/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/.test(value)) {
      throw new Error('Value must be time with HH:MM format');
    }
    return true;
  })
```

Here is the [link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) to see how to use the regex patterns for date formats.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate time by writing a custom validator.

```js
const { body } = require("express-validator");

function isTime(input) {
  // Validate By TimeStamps
  let value = new Date(parseInt(input));
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    throw new Error("Date object is invalid");
  }
  // Validate From ISO Time
  value = new Date(input);
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    throw new Error("Date Object Is invalid");
  }
  return true;
}

body("StartTime").custom(isTime);
```

You can change this snippet of code a little bit to make it better for your needs.

Comment: `parseInt` is redundant here. You can pass a number directly to the constructor.

Comment: But if you want to chack by time stamps you can not do something like this ```new Date("1680947070755")```. and we must use ```parseInt```